# Customization the plotting of a set of data all at once with multiple line legends

Tags: plotting, data, legending

I have a dataset like as follows:

```
data =
  {{{409,63},{420,65},{440,70},{460,73},{480,71},{510,70}},{{409,63},{420,66},{440,76},{460,81},{480,74},{510,79}},{{409,67},{420,62},{440,72},{460,75},{480,82},{510,71}},{{409,66},{420,64},{440,74},{460,75},{480,74},{510,77}},{{409,83},{420,75},{440,72},{460,74},{480,74},{510,77}},{{409,83},{420,75},{440,74},{460,75},{480,71},{510,77}},{{409,73},{420,60},{440,70},{460,73},{480,72},{510,78}},{{409,73},{420,62},{440,78},{460,73},{480,73},{510,60}},{{409,80},{420,69},{440,72},{460,74},{480,77},{510,75}}};
```

I have plotted it with the following code. It's working, but I have the problem that I can not control the legends. I want to change the interval between two legends and break the legends into two columns for clear visualization. Can anyone please help me?

```
ticks[minimum_, maximum_, interval_, length_, label_, digits_, decimaldigs_] := 
  Module[{maxCount, Ticks}, 
    maxCount = Floor[((maximum - minimum)/interval)];
    If[label == 1, 
      Ticks = 
        Table[
          {minimum + (interval*j), 
           If[IntegerQ[#], 
             #, 
             NumberForm[#, {digits, decimaldigs}]]& @ (minimum + (interval*j)), 
           {length, 0}}, 
          {j, 0, maxCount}], 
      Ticks = 
        Table[{minimum + (interval*j), "", {length, 0}}, {j, 0, maxCount}]];
    Join[Ticks]];
    
ticklength = .0120;
ticksleft = ticks[40, 90, 10, ticklength, 1, 6, 0];
ticksdown = ticks[400, 550, 50, ticklength, 1, 3, 0];
    
legend = 
  {lex, Q - 0.05, , Q - 0.1, , Q - 0.15, , Q - 0.25, , Q - 0.3, , Q - 0.4, , 
   Q - 0.6, , Q - 0.8, , Q - 1.0};
    
plotmarker = {●, ▼, ▲, ■, ◆, ✶, ★, ♫, ♪};
    
color = 
  {Hue[0, 1, 0], Hue[0.7, 1, 1], Hue[0.5, 1, 1], Hue[0.4, 0.2, 1], 
   Hue[0.35, 0.6, 1], Hue[0.15, 1, 1], Hue[0.9, 0.2, 1], Hue[0.1, 1, 1], 
   Hue[0.0, 0.6, 1], Hue[0, 1, 1]};
    
legendmarker = 
  {Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["●", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["▼", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["▲", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["■", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["◆", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["✶", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["★", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["♫", {0, 0}]}], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{-0.077, 0}, {0.07, 0}}], Text["♪", {0, 0}]}]};

plot = 
  Show[
    Table[
      ListLinePlot[
        Transpose[
          {Select[
             Drop[PadRight[datafile, {Automatic, Automatic}, "NA"], 1][[All, 2*i - 1]], 
             NumberQ], 
          Select[
            Drop[PadRight[datafile, {Automatic, Automatic}, "NA"], 1][[All, 2*i]], 
            NumberQ]}], 
        PlotLegends -> 
         Placed[SwatchLegend[{legend[[2*i]]}, 
           LegendMarkers -> legendmarker[[i]], LegendMarkerSize -> 5, 
           LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {0.9, 0.4}], 
        PlotStyle -> {Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], color[[i]]}, 
        PlotMarkers -> {plotmarker[[i]], 15} , Frame -> True, 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
        FrameLabel -> 
          {Style[
            "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(ex\)]\) (nm)", Black, 
            FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 16], 
           Style[
             "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(2\)]\)", Black, 
             FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{400, 550}, {45, 90}}, 
        FrameTicks -> {{ticksleft, None}, {ticksdown, None}}, 
        ImageSize -> 500, 
        BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}], {i, 1, 
        Length[data]}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired result more conveniently using a single `ListLinePlot`:

```
legendlabels = Rest[DeleteCases[Null]@legend]; 

ListLinePlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
 PlotMarkers -> Thread[{plotmarker, 15}], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[legendlabels, 
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, LegendLabel -> "lex"],
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[TraditionalForm@Subscript[λ, ex][nm], Black, 
   FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 16], 
  Style[Subscript[A, 2], Black, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 550}, {45, 90}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticksleft, None}, {ticksdown, None}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, create a `LineLegend` separately, and add it to `ListLinePlot` using `Legended`:

```
legends = LineLegend[(Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
   legendlabels, LegendMarkers -> plotmarker, 
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, LegendLabel -> "lex"];

llp = ListLinePlot[data, 
   PlotStyle -> (Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
   PlotMarkers -> Thread[{plotmarker, 15}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style[TraditionalForm@Subscript[λ, ex][nm], 
      Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 16], 
     Style[Subscript[A, 2], Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontSize -> 16]}, PlotRange -> {{400, 550}, {45, 90}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{ticksleft, None}, {ticksdown, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}];

Legended[llp, Placed[legends, Right]]
```

> same picture

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. However I am facing a problem till now while defining legenlabels as "legendlabels = Rest[DeleteCases[Null]@legend];" as it appears an error -"DeleteCases::argbu: DeleteCases called with 1 argument; between 2 and 4 arguments are expected." So, please help to get rid of this.

Comment: @PPyne, try `legendlabels = Rest[DeleteCases[legend, Null]]`

Comment: the error has  removed, but no legend appears at the plot

Comment: @PPyne, looks like it might be version/OS related. What version/os are you using? Does the second method work? Try also `PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[Automatic, legendlabels, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
  LegendLabel -> "lex"], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 
 Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]]` with the first method.

Comment: No, still its not working. I am using Mathematica 9. In the second method plot arises, but at the right side of the plot no leged appears. but linelegend comments just  appears.

Comment: @PPyne, try starting with a fresh kernel. I just checked both methods work in version 9.0 (windows 64bit) (if you use `legendlabels = Rest[DeleteCases[legend, Null]]` with the first method). Please see the second answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The new karnel works fine. However these are shifted by one i.e. first legend appears for 2nd data and \no legend does appear for teh last dataset.

Comment: I have tried without defining legendlabel but manually doing. Its working fine, Thank you once again for the help and support

Answer (score 3):

**Version 9.0 Windows (64-bit)**

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"
> ```

```
legendlabels = Rest[DeleteCases[legend, Null]];

ListLinePlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
 PlotMarkers -> Thread[{plotmarker, 15}], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[legendlabels, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
   LegendLabel -> "lex"], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[TraditionalForm@Subscript[λ, ex][nm], 
    Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 16], 
   Style[Subscript[A, 2], Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
    FontSize -> 16]}, PlotRange -> {{400, 550}, {45, 90}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticksleft, None}, {ticksdown, None}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}]
```

[image]

```
legends = LineLegend[(Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
   legendlabels, LegendMarkers -> plotmarker, 
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, LegendLabel -> "lex"];

llp = ListLinePlot[data, 
   PlotStyle -> (Directive[Dashing[{.0071, 0.015}], #] & /@ color), 
   PlotMarkers -> Thread[{plotmarker, 15}], 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style[TraditionalForm@Subscript[λ, ex][nm], 
      Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 16], 
     Style[Subscript[A, 2], Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontSize -> 16]}, PlotRange -> {{400, 550}, {45, 90}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{ticksleft, None}, {ticksdown, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}];

Legended[llp, Placed[legends, Right]]
```

[image]